# Is my .pfx file a keystore

Tags: pfx

I have a .pfx containing my server certificate for the HTTPS server, and the private key, protected by a password.

Can we say that this file is a keystore? 
When I search *keystore* I only find articles about Java keystore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a PFX file (which follows the PKCS#12 cryptography storage format) such as the one you have does contain a key so it would be a keystore.

You can use PKCS#12 files natively as a keystore for most crypto implementations - for instance for its usage as a keystore in Java see the accepted answer for ["Keystore type: which one to use?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540061/1127637) for a very illustrative description on the various types of keystores.